# SAS Macro to create multiple lags on longitudinal data

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have an unbalanced longitudinal dataset Store_data:

```
Period    Store     Sales
 Jan        A         12
 Feb        A         10
 March      A         8
 April      A         3
 Jan        B         5
 Feb        B         19
 March      B         7
 April      B         8
 Jan        C         5
 Feb        C         19
 March      C         7
 April      C         8
```

At present, in order to create Sales lags of up to 2 years, I have to manually create the lag for each order. I.e.

```
data Store_lag;
    set Store_data;
    by Store;

    Sales_Lag1=lag(Sales);
    if first.Store then Sales_Lag1=.;

    Sales_Lag2=lag(Sales_Lag1);
    if first.Store then Sales_Lag2=.;

    *etc.....;
run;
```

My question would be if there is a macro to create such variables? It gets especially tedious when the number of lag order gets large.

Comment: Do you have SAS/ETS licensed (time series)?

Comment: Nope. I know we can use proc expand in ETS but I only have SAS base/STAT installed.

Comment: Wow a valid use case for the lag function! =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array processing really should do just fine here.  Here's an example.

```
data want;
  set have;
  by store;

  array lags[1:4] lags0-lags3;
  retain lags:;

  if first.store then 
     call missing(of lags[*]);    *clear out the array for each store;
  do _i = dim(lags) to 2 by -1;   *move the stack to the right;
    lags[_i] = lags[_i-1];
  end;
  lags[1] = sales;                *set the first one;
  drop lags0;                     *lags0 is the current sales, of course;
run;
```